# returning empty array in coreData

Tags: ios

Hello friends I am working with coreData and I am new it..I read official documentation of coredata and tried to play with it...

So what I did ,I am writing in steps..

1.I first created the windowbased project with coredata option selected

2.I opened xcdatamodeld and added one Entity with name "Employee" and three attributes..a)name b)Dept c) Designation..

3.I created the employee.h and employee.m

4.Now in my FirstTableViewController.m
I wrote this code

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        Employee *emp = (Employee *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Employee" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

        Employee *emp1 = (Employee *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Employee" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];


        m_employeeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        [emp setName:@"Jack"];
        [emp setDept:@"Accounts"];
        [emp setDesignation:@"Manager"];

        [emp1 setName:@"Joseph"];
        [emp1 setDept:@"Finance"];
        [emp1 setDesignation:@"Manager"];

        [m_employeeArray addObject:emp];
        [m_employeeArray addObject:emp1];


//Code to save the data..
        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            // Handle the error.
        }

        NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Employee" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
        [request setEntity:entity];


       m_mutableFetchResults = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error]mutableCopy];
        if (m_mutableFetchResults == nil) {
            // Handle the error.
        }


        for (Employee *info in m_mutableFetchResults)
        {
            NSLog(@"Name: %@", emp.Name);
            NSLog(@"Name: %@", emp.Dept);
            NSLog(@"Name: %@", emp.Designation);
        }

    }
```

and my tabel delegate methods are below

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [m_employeeArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    Employee *emp = (Employee *)[m_employeeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = emp.Name;


    return cell;
}
```

and So when I load the view I get the cell filled with two names i.e Jack and Joseph
Here u can see that I am saving the data into m_mutableFetchResults and showing the output in console and every time the project is run the data is getting saved and its works fine..

Now I created another tableviewcontroller called SecondTableViewController

so that on didselectrow of FirstTableViewController I will show the secondTableViewController filled with m_mutableFetchResults

so below is my

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.

     SecondTableViewController *detailViewController = [[SecondTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondTableViewController" bundle:nil];

    [detailViewController setSavedArray:m_mutableFetchResults];
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
     [detailViewController release];

}
```

and I am filling the secondTableViewController with [savedArray count] but the array in secondTableViewController is empty..I am not understanding where I am goin wrong...

So friends,I have tried by best to make you all understand my problem...

So please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

where do you try to get the elements of savedArray in SecondTableViewController?
if you try to get them in -init method the array will be nil at that time. the pushViewController:animated: method will invoke -viewDidLoad method and you should see the results.
ps: I recommend you to not retain the savedArray in SecontTableViewController because it can crash your code if any objects change in runtime.

Comment: Hi ,thanks for your reply,In seconviewTableViewcontroller, on ViewDidLoad method,I first initialized the savedarray,and then
I have used it in table delegate methods.

Comment: Hello friends,please help me out